# While loop in Bash script removing first line when reading from file

Tags: bash, macos, while-loop

I'm trying to pass a file into a script which will take each line and convert it to be compatible with Mac. It does that by sed'ing the line and then cutting out relevant information and putting it into a variable to be used later. So if a line in the source file is: windows_cmd \ip.address\sharename\rest\of\path "\download\location"

Sed will remove everything in-between the "" then convert the "\" to "/". Afterwards I want to use the "/" as a delimiter to cut out relevant info like server_ip, share_name and etc.

Whenever the while loop runs through it always skips the first line in the file AND I can't get my script to output the variables so i can troubleshoot.

```
xcopy /y  \\111.22.3.444\DATA\400221\800\4002218002360 "~/desktop\4002218002360\"
xcopy /y  \\111.22.3.444\DATA\612608\807\612608807228 "~/desktop\612608807228\"
xcopy /y  \\111.22.3.444\DATA\194491\126\194491126025 "~/desktop\194491126025\"
```

My source file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="$1"

while read i; 
    do sed s/\".*$// | sed s/'\\'/'\/'/g;
        export SERVER_NAME=$(echo "$i" | cut -d / -f 4); 
        export SHARE_NAME=$(echo "$i" | cut -d / -f 5);
    done < $1

    echo ${SERVER_NAME}
    echo ${SHARE_NAME}
exit 0
```

I expected an output of :

```
xcopy /y  //111.22.3.444/DATA/400221/800/4002218002360
xcopy /y  //111.22.3.444/DATA/612608/807/612608807228
xcopy /y  //111.22.3.444/DATA/194491/126/194491126025
```

But instead i get :

```
xcopy /y  //111.22.3.444/DATA/612608/807/612608807228
xcopy /y  //111.22.3.444/DATA/194491/126/194491126025
```

<2 blank lines>

Comment: Your `sed` commands are missing quotes or have them in the wrong places. It's not necessary to `export` the variables unless you need to use them in the environment of subprocesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is poorly constructed.  For analysis, let's simplify it to:

```
while read i; do 
   sed cmd
done < $1
```

`read` reads one line of the input file.  Then `sed` is started, inheriting its stdin from the loop.  Since the first line of data has already been consumed, `sed` starts reading at the second line.  It consumes all of the data and exits.  Then `read` is executed again, and returns non-zero (since there's no data left).  What is the purpose of the `while read` loop?

I *think* what you're trying to do can be accomplished with:

```
< $1 sed ... |
while IFS=/ read a b c SERVER_NAME SHARE_NAME; do
    echo ${SERVER_NAME}
    echo ${SHARE_NAME}
done
```

But it seems like it would be cleaner to do:

```
awk '{print $3}' $1 |
while IFS=\\ read a b c SERVER_NAME SHARE_NAME; do 
    echo $SERVER_NAME
    echo $SHARE_NAME
done
```

Comment: The poster wants to convert dos to unix lines and convert `\\` into `/` in paths with `sed`

Comment: @LéaGris is correct. I'm taking a file full of dos lines, converting them to unix-style then using cut to pull out server addresses to then use to connect to the server and copy the files I need. I am clearly a noob so I'm not surprised my loop is all messed up. There will be instances where I will have more then 3 lines in a file so I am trying to play with and understand the "while IFS=\\ read a b c SERVER_NAME SHARE_NAME;" of your example. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The while read loop works on one line at a time.  Each line of the file will run one iteration of the loop. Setting IFS allows `read` to split the line so you don't need to use `cut`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you for your explanation. It led me to learn some new concepts that were very helpful. I was able to get the missing line with your advice but couldn't quite get the string formatted/processed as needed. I ended up using `while read -r line; 
 do  line=${line/\\\\///}
  line=${line//\\//}
  line=${line%%\"*\"}`

Answer (score 0):

Why not give `awk` a try?

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="$1"

# change all \ to / in the third column of input text:
awk '{gsub(/\\/,"/",$3);print}' $input_file

# change the fourth column, too:
awk '{gsub(/\\/,"/",$3);gsub(/\\/,"/",$4);print}' $input_file
```

Also, once you have code the produces all of the correct command strings, you can directly pipe to bash to run them one-by-one, e.g.,

```
awk '{gsub(/\\/,"/",$3);gsub(/\\/,"/",$4);print}' $input_file | bash
```

...but make sure the commands are correct first before adding the `| bash`.

Comment: Hey, I initially used awk to pull out some of the information I needed but didn't use it to convert the backslashes. Ultimately, after I got the slashes sorted i used them as delimiter's in cut which looked nicer than awk.